# Cannot use GetSqlValues Method from SqlDataReader c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

I make post method to select data from sql server, it works but i cant return all the data that i select and only can get one data

```
   [HttpPost]
        public Object SelectData([FromBody]DataEmployee employee)
        {
            DataEmployee Data = new DataEmployee();

            string ConeectionString = "";
            using (SqlConnection openCon = new SqlConnection(ConeectionString))
            {       
                openCon.Open();

                SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("SELECT [ID],[FirstName] ,[LastName] ,[Gender] ,[Salary] FROM[dbo].[employeesData] WHERE[FirstName]= @zip", openCon);

                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@zip", employee.FirstName );
                int result = command.ExecuteNonQuery();
                SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
                // result gives the -1 output.. but on insert its 1
                if (reader.HasRows)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("\t{0}\t{1}", reader.GetName(0),
                        reader.GetName(1));

                    if (reader.Read())
                    {
                       // Console.WriteLine("\t{0}\t{1}", reader.GetInt32(0),
                         //   reader.GetString(1));

                    }
                    //    reader.NextResult();
                 //   return reader.GetString(3);   

                }
                else
                {
                    return "Data is Empty";
                }

                return reader.GetString(2);
            }       
        }
```

As you can see above i use `getstring` to return the data and that's make i only get one specified column , in here i want return all column that i get from the query, so i look all method that available from SQL Data Reader and found `GetSqlValues` that will fill an array of object that contains the value from for all column in the record, but i am struggling to make it works.

I already tried     `return reader.GetSqlValues(Data);` 
But it shows error message cant convert to object. Can anyone help me here i need to return all column here

Comment: Maybe you want to change your connection credentials now...

Comment: ahah i forgot to hide my data sqlconnection

Comment: @TheodorusAgumGumilang I have redacted that from history, but you should consider that password compromised and change it

Comment: @MarcGravell Maybe it's a good idea if SO will try to analyze text and detect potential information leaks like `Password=..`

Comment: its okay it only contain dummy data, but thanks for your concern

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it like below :

```
string val="";
if (reader.HasRows)
{
    while (reader.Read())
    {
        val += "ID = " + reader[0].ToString() + "; Name = " + reader[1].ToString();
    }
}
else
{
    return "Data is Empty";
}

reader.Close();
return val;
```

If you know the column name to show, then you can use it :

```
while (reader.Read())
{
    Console.WriteLine("\t{0}\t{1}", reader["ColumnOneName"].ToString(),
    reader["ColumnTwoName"].ToString());
}
```

Comment: i already tried that and only get 1 column,  or maybe i should use like this  reader["Column1" , "Column2", "Column3"].ToString()); ?

Comment: Also don't use this line `return reader.GetString(2);` you have at the end, return a value without using `reader` and don't forget to close the reader by `reader.Close();`

Comment: i tried to return the data like this {
        "ID": 1,
        "FirstName": "Theodorus",
        "LastName": "Gumilang",
        "Gender": "Male",
        "Salary": 1234
    },

but i only return 1 column instead,and i already tried your answer and still only get 1 Column

Comment: If this answer helped you solving your problem, don't forget to mark this answer as useful(upvote) and accept the answer [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Comment: yes , i edit your source code and to get list of array and return the data [
    "3",
    "Andreas",
    "Waskito",
    "Male",
    "1234567890"
]  , as you can see there is no FirstName, ID etc when i tried this   List<DataEmployee> rawData = null; it shows error message cant convert from string to DataEmployee

Comment: can you help me return the data to IEnumerable collection ? that will help me

Comment: You are expanding your original question! Please post a new question if you have more issues, you can give reference to this question.

Answer (score 0):

To return all columns and all rows returned from the query.

```
int count = reader.FieldCount;
List<List<string>> data = new List<List<string>>();
while(reader.Read()) {
    data.Add(Enumerable.Range(0,count -1).Select(it => reader.GetValue(it)));    
}
```